# How to initialize a component

Tags: laravel

I am working with laravel 8.

I want to create a component "select-family". Which will be a simple select.

I created the component like that :

> php artisan make:component SelectFamily

This command created 2 files :

- the "views/components/select-family.blade.php"
- the "View/Components/SelectFamily.php"

In the SelectFamily, I wrote :

```
public function render()
{   
    return view('components.select-family', [
        'families' => Family::all()
    ]);
}
```

And in blade file ,I have :

```
<select name="family" id="family">
<option value="">--all--</option>
@foreach ($families as $family)
    <option value="{{ $family->id }}">{{ $family->name }}</option>
@endforeach</select>
```

At least, my component is called like that :

```
@component('components.select-family')
```

I have this error :

> Undefined variable: families

I tried a lot of things without success.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a public parameter in the component class and it will be automatically injected to the blade.

```
public $families;

public function __construct()
{   
    $this->families = Family::all();
}

public function render()
{   
    return view('components.select-family');
}
```

#### Notice:

If you've deployed on a **shared host** and it throws same error, introduce your components in the `register()` method of `AppServiceProvider` or introduce a standalone provider for this purpose.

*Custom Introducing*

```
public function register()
{
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::component(Component::class, 'component-name');
}
```